# Returning Module Class instead of Model Class with self.class Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, constants, self

I am trying to DRY my code by implementing modules. However, I have constants stored in models (not the module) that I am trying to access with self.class.

Here are (I hope) the relevant snippets:

```
module Conversion
  def constant(name_str)
    self.class.const_get(name_str.upcase)
  end
end

module DarkElixir
  def dark_elixir(th_level)
    structure.map { |name_str| structure_dark_elixir(name_str, th_level) if constant(name_str)[0][:dark_elixir_cost] }.compact.reduce(:+)
  end
end

class Army < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Conversion, DarkElixir

  TH_LEVEL = [...]
end

def structure_dark_elixir(name_str, th_level)
  name_sym = name_str.to_sym
  Array(0..send(name_sym)).map { |level| constant(name_str)[level][:dark_elixir_cost] }.reduce(:+) * TH_LEVEL[th_level][sym_qty(name)]
end
```

When I place the structure_dark_elixir method inside the DarkElixir module, I get an error, "uninitialized constant DarkElixir::TH_LEVEL"

While if I place it inside the Army class, it finds the appropriate constant.

I believe it is because I am not scoping the self.constant_get correctly. I would like to keep the method in question in the module as other models need to run the method referencing their own TH_LEVEL constants.

How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use class methods?

```
module DarkElixir
  def dark_elixir(th_level)
    # simplified example
    th_level * self.class.my_th_level
  end
end

class Army < ActiveRecord::Base
  include DarkElixir

  def self.my_th_level
    5
  end
end
```

Comment: I believe that would require that I add the self.my_th_level class method to each model I include the DarkElixir module.  I am hoping to dynamically add the method to all models via the module.

Comment: But you said: `other models need to run the method referencing their own TH_LEVEL constants`. So are you trying to make 'th_level' (constant or method, doesn't matter) specific for every class, or the same for every class which included your DarkElixir module?

Comment: hm, I just saw 'working on edit' and removed my comment to not interfere with it

Comment: Each model has its own TH_LVL constant--with unique information. Each model will need an identical method with which to perform calculations using its respective TH_LVL constant.  I am trying to store the method in the module to avoid repetition. The constant(name_str) function behaves properly when called withing a Model. However when called within the DarkElixir module, it looks for the constant inside the module, not the respective model.

Comment: Yes, and I suggest you just avoid messing with dark magic of `#const_get`. Just use class method *instead* of constant. So I suggest you just use `self.my_th_level` (name however you like it) *instead* of TH_LVL constant. Method which used that constant will just use `self.my_th_level` instead (and that call will go to Model class, which has its own my_th_level defined with specific for given Model value).

Comment: I see what you are saying now--use a class method as a pseudoconstant. I'll give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Well, you might as well consider accepting an answer if that works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Ugh. Method in question uses two constants.  It was the second constant that was tripping up, not the first.  Added "self.class::" prior to the second constant--back in business.

```
def structure_dark_elixir(name_str, th_lvl)
  name_sym = name_str.to_sym
  Array(0..send(name_sym)).map { |level| constant(name_str)[level][:dark_elixir_cost] }.reduce(:+) * self.class::TH_LEVEL[th_lvl][sym_qty(name_str)]
end
```